# Element created from a document but not appended: need to remove it explicitly?

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxp

I need to create a temporary DOM-element which is independent from my main document. I do it by using my main document to create an element but not appending it to the tree.

```
Element temporaryParentElement = document.createElement(PERMISSIONSET);
```

It is used to build tables in a dialog. After the dialog is closed i don't need this element anymore so I tried to remove it:

```
document.removeChild(temporaryParentElement);
```

This resulted in an exception:

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_FOUND_ERR: An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist.
```

If i understand it correctly the created node cannot be removed if it isn't a part of the tree. Do I need to append it to the tree and then call remove method? Or does the garbage collector take care about this element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Element *creation* is different from appending or removing it to an existing tree. You use that `document` reference to create the element, but then append it to some other element. You can remove it using the reference of that element.

The method `removeChild` removes an element from a tree where it was added before (with `appendChild` or parsed when the document was read).

You have to find the element that represents the parent of that element in order to remove it. Suppose the parent is `dialog`. You would use:

```
dialog.removeChild(temporaryParentElement);
```

Comment: The element doesn't have any parent. `temporaryParentElement.getParentNode()` returns null.

Comment: If you didn't add the element to any tree, then you don't need to remove it from one.

Comment: So will it be removed from the memory by garbage collector? I am asking because I don't want to "clutter" the document with dummy elements.

Comment: Yes. If the only reference you have to that object is  `temporaryParentElement` (if you did not append it to any element, nor added to any collection, etc.), it will be available for garbage collection when that reference is no longer in context.